# What is the name of this manga with a girl pretending to be a mermaid?

Tags: a-lollypop-or-a-bullet

So a couple years ago I was read this manga, then I finished, because it was an incomplete series, but then I lost it.

Basically, what I remember is that there was this girl who wanted to join the army after she finished school to help support her mother, and she meets this very weird girl who thinks she is a mermaid and constantly drinks water out of a huge bottle. The girl has weird marks and bruises on her skin, but she brushes is off as "mermaid burns" or something else.

Then, a celebrity comes to the town, who was super famous and the army girl liked him a little bit. Some stuff happens, and then in the end, it turns out that the celebrity was the "mermaid girls" father and he was abusing her. The series finished after that.

Please help, it was a very sad manga!

Comment: Please be more specific, as in how many years ago (eg. 5, 10 years ago). If possible, please give a description of the characters's appearances, it helps a lot in our search.

Comment: What was the art style? Can you attach a picture of a manga that uses a similar style?

Comment: @AstralSea I think the army-aspiring girl was blonde and the mermaid girl had dark short hair.

Comment: @Tamz_m I don't remember the art style. I read the manga on my old laptop so I don't have any screenshots I might have made.

Comment: @AstralSea also I read it about 2012-2013 ish. End of 2012 definitely.

Answer (score 8):

The manga you are looking for is:
[Satou Kashi no Dangan wa Uchinukenai](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Manga/SatouKashiNoDanganWaUchinukenai) 
(Sugar Candy Bullets Can’t Pierce Anything).

[image]

The following summaries are included on the website:

> When a strange new girl by the name of Umino Mokuzu transfers in from
>   Tokyo and declares that she is a "Mermaid", she quickly becomes the
>   center of attention. Noticing that Nagisa is the only classmate that
>   seems to have no interest in her, Umino quickly decides that they
>   should become "precious friends". Despite Nagisa's objections, Umino
>   begins to follow her wherever she goes.

and

> Umino's rockstar father is shown to be aloof towards her at best and
>   emotionally abusive at worst, once leaving her behind in a grocery
>   store parking lot simply because a defective shopping cart made him
>   angry and that's only the tip of the iceberg.

[image]